# c# and WebRequest: change contentlenght

Tags: c#, post, webrequest

I've to send some post to a server, so i create a webrequest set the method, the content type and the content lenght. It works ok.
Now I want to send a second post so I need to change the contentlenght but I give an exception and i don't understand why.

Comment: Post your code and the exception, please.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us the error details, but I ***suspect*** the first request has not yet completed. IMO, unless you are doing something particularly subtle, it is often a good idea to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which is a wrapper around `WebRequest` (etc) that greatly simplifies the API - for example you can just call the `UploadData` method, or `DownloadString`, etc. These are easy to call successively.